# Docker. How to get environment variable in nginx access_by_lua_file lua script

Tags: nginx, docker, lua

I have `nginx` in a docker container, where `FORWARD_LOG` env variable has value 1.

In `nginx.conf`:

```
env FORWARD_LOG;
```

My server config:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name nginx;

    location / {
        #resolvers
        #resolvers_template

        set_by_lua $forward_log 'return os.getenv("FORWARD_LOG")';

        proxy_pass $scheme://$host$request_uri;

        lua_code_cache on;
        access_by_lua_file /etc/nginx/domain.lua;

        allow all;
    }
}
```

Now I want to get this variable in `domain.lua` script. I tried different methods:

`local FORWARD_LOG = ngx.var.forward_log;` gives an empty result.
`local FORWARD_LOG = $forward_log;` gives `unexpected symbol near '$'`.
`local FORWARD_LOG = os.getenv("FORWARD_LOG")';` - returns `nil`.

How can I do that ?